# Error making const correct Vulkan CreateDebugMessenger function

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors, vulkan

I seem to have run into a bit of a pickle.  I was attempting to modify some functions I made while following a Vulkan tutorial, which is essentially the function below but minus the function parameters and return type.  Everything worked just fine creating an instance, so I thought there wouldn't be a problem doing this with VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT.

Well, the linker kept stopping me and telling me "Undefined symbol: _vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT", and after confirming it was not a header loop issue or type mismatch, I was thoroughly confused.  It now works, but only because I made it inline, which shouldn't have changed anything right?  If anyone can explain why inlining changed anything, and how to make it work normally I would be very appreciative.

```
VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* ApplicationComponentConstructor::setupDebugMessenger(VkInstance* const instance) const
{
    if (!enableValidationLayers) return nullptr;

    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* newDebugMessenger = new VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT;

    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT createInfo {};
    createInfo = generateDebugMessengerCreateInfo();

    if (vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(*instance, &createInfo, nullptr, newDebugMessenger) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to setup debug messenger!");

    return newDebugMessenger;
}
```

This function definition is in a file called "componentConstructor.cpp" and is a post-definition of a member of the "ApplicationComponentConstructor" class in "componentConstructor.hpp".  Here is the class for reference:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#ifndef componentConstructor_hpp
#define componentConstructor_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#ifdef NDEBUG
    const bool enableValidationLayers = false;
#else
    const bool enableValidationLayers = true;
#endif

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 750;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 750;

class ApplicationComponentConstructor
{
public:
    friend class GameApplication;

private:
    // Start of static helper functions
    using VkDUMessageSeverity = VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT;
    using VkDUMessageType = VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT;
    using VkDUMCallBackData = VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT;

    static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(VkDUMessageSeverity messageSeverity, VkDUMessageType messageType, const VkDUMCallBackData* pCallBackData, void* pUserData);

    static std::vector<char> readFile(const std::string &fileName);
    // End of static helper functions

    // INSTANCE CREATION FUNCTIONS
    VkInstance* createInstance() const;

    // DEBUG MESSENGER CREATION FUNCTIONS
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* setupDebugMessenger(VkInstance* const instance) const;

    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT generateDebugMessengerCreateInfo() const;

    // SURFACE CREATION FUNCTIONS
    VkSurfaceKHR* createSurface();

    // LOGICAL DEVICE CREATION FUNCTIONS
    VkDevice* createLogicalDevice();
};

#endif /* componentConstructor_hpp */
```

And last, but not least, here is the build log from Xcode:

```
Showing Recent Messages

Prepare build
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from memory



Build target VulkanProject of project VulkanProject with configuration Debug

CompileC /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/componentConstructor.o /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Xcode\ Projects/VulkanProject/VulkanProject/componentConstructor.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'VulkanProject' from project 'VulkanProject')
    cd /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Xcode\ Projects/VulkanProject
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++1z -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/VulkanProject-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/VulkanProject-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/VulkanProject-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/VulkanProject-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/componentConstructor.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/componentConstructor.dia -c /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Xcode\ Projects/VulkanProject/VulkanProject/componentConstructor.cpp -o /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/componentConstructor.o

Ld /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug/VulkanProject normal x86_64 (in target 'VulkanProject' from project 'VulkanProject')
    cd /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Xcode\ Projects/VulkanProject
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/HEAD-e65de29/lib -F/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VulkanProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VulkanProject_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -lvulkan.1 -framework vulkan -lglfw.3.4 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VulkanProject.build/Debug/VulkanProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VulkanProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanProject-gbxmwgztncvnifafqcyuyrehhkxs/Build/Products/Debug/VulkanProject

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT", referenced from:
      ApplicationComponentConstructor::setupDebugMessenger(VkInstance_T**) const in componentConstructor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



Build failed    4/15/20, 11:39 PM    0.6 seconds
```

Heres a link to the tutorial I followed, if it helps somehow: https://vulkan-tutorial.com.

Comment: Extension functions have to be *loaded* explicitly.  See [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/czluzc/undefined_reference_to/)  post.

Comment: @trojanfoe oh my gosh! I did have the function loader, I just used the wrong function!  But, why did it link when I made the function inline?

Comment: I am not sure.  You need to be careful that you follow the official guidelines on obtaining these kinds of functions as with some Vulkan implementations they may be available to link directly while on others not so.

Comment: Your `enableValidationLayers` is practically `constexpr` value, so your inline function gets optimized away after `return nullptr`. @trojanfoe One of you please compose an answer.